# Windows Utility to search files with certain criteria and act on them

Tags: windows, file-search

I am looking for a Windows utility which can search for files fulfilling certain criteria (e.g., file type is "Word" (.doc or .docx), with last modify date older than 1 year ago), ***and*** perform several actions on them all (e.g., delete them, or move them somewhere else, or copy them and change their archive bits).

What do you recommend?

Comment: which version of Windows? Vista+ builtin `forfiles` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) seems obvious choice for simple tasks, `powershell` for anything else.

Comment: @wmz: its an answer..post it as one.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be Cygwin, but it's a bit heavyweight if you want to do *just that*. You can get a standalone version of `find`+`xargs` with [findutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm). You can then use this the same way you would on a Linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/) for this kind of stuff. It displays found files in one window and you can do all usual file operations on the found result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Vista and later builtin `forfiles` ([technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) seems obvious choice for simple tasks.

([from above ms page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), modified)
Syntax:

```
forfiles [/p <Path>] [/m <SearchMask>] [/s] [/c "<Command>"] [/d [{+|-}][{<Date>|<Days>}]]
```

Forfiles can select files and then run a command on them by:

> File name.
>   File name without extension.
>   File name extension.
>   Full path of the file. 
>   Relative path of the file.
>   Whether it's a file or directory.
>   File size, in bytes. Last modified date stamp on the file.
>   Last modified time stamp on the file.

To run internal command (like `dir` `attrib` and so on) you would need to use `cmd /c command` syntax.  If you need to run more than one command you can chain them with `&`, or put them in a batch file.

If you need something more complex (combining masks etc.) I would use  `powershell`.